# Server closes connection when client sends a message

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to learn the server/client paradigm. I have created a server that listens for connection and input on given port.

My problem is that, when a client connects and sends a message, the server closes the connection, and stops listening for input. What I want, is that when a clients sends a message, the sever should not close the connection, but still keep getting input from the connected client. I know that I can only handle one client at a time, since I am not creating a Thread for each client, but this should not cause the server to close connection as soon as the client sends a message.

Here is my server code:

```
public void startServer() {
        try {
            IPAddress iAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.10");
            TcpListener tcpListner = new TcpListener(iAd, 9000);

            tcpListner.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("The server is running on port: 9000");
            Console.WriteLine("The local End point is: " + tcpListner.LocalEndpoint + "\nWaiting for a connection");

            Socket socket = tcpListner.AcceptSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("\nConnection from client: " + socket.RemoteEndPoint);

            byte[] b =new byte[100];
            int k = socket.Receive(b);

            for (int i=0;i<k;i++) {
                Console.Write("Recieved: " + Convert.ToChar(b[i]));

            }

            ASCIIEncoding asen=new ASCIIEncoding();
            socket.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
            Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");
            /* clean up */            
            socket.Close();
            tcpListner.Stop();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

And the client code

```
public void StartClient(string servToConnectTo, int port) {
        try{
            client.Connect(servToConnectTo, port);

            Console.WriteLine("Connected to server: " + servToConnectTo + " on port: " + port);
            Console.WriteLine ("Write input to server...");

            String input = Console.ReadLine();
            Stream stream = client.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] b = asen.GetBytes(input);
            Console.WriteLine("Sending...");

            stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);

            byte[] bb = new byte[100];
            int k = stream.Read(bb, 0, 100);

            for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));
            }

            client.Close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine (e.Message);
        }                           
    }
```

I guess I need a `while loop` some place, but not sure where

Comment: In your server code - probably a couple of them.. do you need it to receive more than 1 message? (per client)

Comment: I want that when a client is connected, he should be able to keep writing stuff to the server, until he choses to disconnect. Right now, the client can only write 1 word, and when he sends that word, the server prints that word, and then closes connection instead of keep waiting for more messages from that client

Comment: So, you need a loop round the server side from declaring "b" through to "sent acknowledgement" ..

Comment: I recommend looking at the MSDN examples : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx